# How to set text size in legend?

Tags: r, plot

I have tried this

```
#!/usr/bin/R

fcm <-c(13.0,12.5,11.8)
gk  <-c(10.9 ,   10.5  ,  10.2)
gg  <-c(12.0 ,   11.0 ,   10.8)
data1 <- rbind(fcm,gk,gg)
colnames(data1) <- c(5,6,7)

barplot(as.matrix(data1),ylim=c(0,15),main="P wave",
        xlab="number of clusters",ylab="traveltime rms(ms)",
        col=c("red", "black", "green"), beside=TRUE)
op <- par(cex=.64)
legend(legend = c("fcm","gk","gg"), fill = c( "red", "black", "green"), 
"top", horiz=TRUE,text.font=3)
par(op)

dev.copy(png,"s1.png",width=4,height=4,units="in",res=200)
dev.off()
```

When image appears,R graphics device 2 Active looks fine.But save image has overlapping of words in legend.
[image]

How to solve this?

Comment: try `dev.print` instead...or better start with `png("filepath")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `dev.copy` to save your image, you can call `png` before "drawing" it :

```
png("Z:/GES - catalogue signatures/biblio/cdf pour Wolf/s1.png", width=4,height=4,units="in",res=200)
barplot(as.matrix(data1),ylim=c(0,15),main="P wave",
         xlab="number of clusters",ylab="traveltime rms(ms)",
         col=c("red", "black", "green"), beside=TRUE)
op <- par(cex=.64)
legend(legend = c("fcm","gk","gg"), fill = c( "red", "black", "green"), 
 "top", horiz=TRUE,text.font=3)
par(op)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Other options are to set a larger `width` in the call to `png` or playing with the `text.width` argument of `legend`.

Comment: @nicola, indeed ! (I usually spend quite some time tuning the different parameters so the image looks just perfect ;-) )

Comment: @CathG Works perfect now.